# How to Separate Letters Inside a List?

Tags: python, list, cryptography

I have this piece of code

```
First = "152 162 152 145 162 167 150 172 153 162 145 170 141 16"
First = list(First.split())
solve = " "
for i in First:
    solve += chr(int(i, base=8))
print(solve)
```

what I stuck in, is how to separate letters inside a list instead of print all letter together. I tried `solve = (solve.split(",") for sep in solve)` but it's give me an error. what I will do exactly is to take an `ord()` value of each letter and subtract 4 then return it to str by `chr()`

Comment: What is the output/result you want here?

Comment: a list of letters = ["j","e","j" ....etc ]

Comment: The generator comprehension need some modification to work, try this `solve = (sep.split(",") for sep in solve)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```py
data = "152 162 152 145 162 167 150 172 153 162 145 170 141 16"
output = [chr(int(x, base=8)) for x in data.split()]
print(output) # ['j', 'r', 'j', 'e', 'r', 'w', 'h', 'z', 'k', 'r', 'e', 'x', 'a', '\x0e']
```

If you just want to use your original code, then simply `list(solve)` will make the list of characters. But note that there is a (perhaps unintended) blank at the beginning of your `solve`; this happens because you initiated `solve` with `" "`, not `""`.

---

If you want to subtract 4 from each integer representation of the characters (as you explained in the question), to get the string, then

```py
data = "152 162 152 145 162 167 150 172 153 162 145 170 141 16"
output = ''.join(chr(int(x, base=8) - 4) for x in data.split())
print(output) # fnfansdvgnat]
```

would provide you with a shortcut.

Comment: Worked well thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list directly instead of string as follows:

```
First = "152 162 152 145 162 167 150 172 153 162 145 170 141 16"
First = list(First.split())
solve = []
for i in First:
    solve.append( chr(int(i, base=8)))
print(solve)

Output: ['j', 'r', 'j', 'e', 'r', 'w', 'h', 'z', 'k', 'r', 'e', 'x', 'a', '\x0e']
```

You can convert solve to a string as below:

```
''.join(solve)
```